# Absolute value of an exponential sum

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-sum

Consider the following sequence
$$
x_n=\Bigl|\sum_{t=1}^n\exp\Bigl\{2\pi i\Bigl[\frac1d-\frac {\lfloor n/d\rfloor}n\Bigr]t\Bigr\}\Bigr|
$$
with some fixed positive integer $d$ such that $d<n$. I am trying to establish a lower bound for $x_n$ for all large values of $n$.

> Is it true that $x_n\ge cn$ with some absolute positive constant $c$ for large values of $n$?

If $n$ is an integer multiple of $d$, then $x_n=n$ since $1/d-\lfloor n/d\rfloor/n=0$. In the general case, we have that
$$
\frac1d-\frac{\lfloor n/d\rfloor}n
=\frac{n-d\lfloor n/d\rfloor}d\cdot\frac1n
$$
and
$$
0\le\frac{n-d\lfloor n/d\rfloor}{d}<1
$$
so it seems that $x_n$ should be close to $n$ for large values of $n$, but I have no idea if it is possible to show this rigorously.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I found my error and corrected it.
I also made the proof simpler.)

$x_n=\Bigl|\sum_{t=1}^n\exp\Bigl\{2\pi i\Bigl[\frac1d-\frac {\lfloor n/d\rfloor}n\Bigr]t\Bigr\}\Bigr|
$.

I will show that

$\begin{array}\\
x_n
&=\dfrac{|\sin(  \pi\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})|}{|\sin(  \frac{\pi}{n}\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})|}\\
&\ge n\frac{|\sin(  \pi\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})|}{|(\pi\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})|}\\
&\ge n(1-\frac16(\pi\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})^2)\\
\end{array}
$

---

Let
$a
=2\pi(\dfrac1d-\frac {\lfloor \frac{n}{d}\rfloor}{n})
=\dfrac{2\pi}{n}(\dfrac{n}{d}-\lfloor \dfrac{n}{d}\rfloor)
=\dfrac{2\pi}{n}\left\{\dfrac{n}{d}\right\}
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
x_n
&=\Bigl|\sum_{t=1}^ne^{  i at}\Bigr|\\
&=\Bigl|e^{  i a}\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}e^{  i at}\Bigr|\\
&=\Bigl|e^{  i a}\dfrac{1-e^{  i a n}}{1-e^{  i a}}\Bigr|\\
&=|e^{  i a}|\Bigl|\dfrac{1-e^{  i a n}}{1-e^{  i a}}\Bigr|\\
&=\Bigl|\dfrac{1-e^{  i a n}}{1-e^{  i a}}\Bigr|
\qquad\text{since } |ab| = |a|\,|b|\\
&=\dfrac{|2\sin(  n a/2)|}{2|\sin(  a/2)|}
\qquad\text{since } |1-e^{ix}| = 2\sin(x/2)
\text{ (see below)}\\
&=\dfrac{|\sin(  n a/2)|}{|\sin(  a/2)|}\\
&=\dfrac{|\sin(  n \frac{2\pi}{n}\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\}/2)|}{|\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n}\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\}/2)|}\\
&=\dfrac{|\sin(  \pi\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})|}{|\sin(  \frac{\pi}{n}\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})|}\\
&=\dfrac{|\sin(  \pi\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})(  \frac{\pi}{n}\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})|}{|(\frac{\pi}{n}\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})\sin(  \frac{\pi}{n}\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})|}\\
&=n\dfrac{|\sin(  \pi\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})(  \frac{\pi}{n}\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})|}{|(\pi\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})\sin(\frac{\pi}{n}\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})|}\\
&\ge n\dfrac{|\sin(  \pi\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})|}{|(\pi\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})|}
\qquad \text{since } \sin(x) \le x\\
&\ge n(1-\frac16(\pi\left\{\frac{n}{d}\right\})^2)
\qquad \text{since } \sin(x) \ge x-x^3/6\\
\end{array}
$

Auxiliary results.

$\begin{array}\\
|1-e^{ix}|
&=|1-(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))|\\
&=|1-\cos(x)-i\sin(x)|\\
&=\sqrt{(1-\cos(x))^2+\sin^2(x)}\\
&=\sqrt{1-2\cos(x)+\cos(x)^2+\sin^2(x)}\\
&=\sqrt{2-2\cos(x)}\\
&=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}\\
&=2\sqrt{(1-\cos(x))/2}\\
&=2|\sin(x/2)|\\
|1+e^{ix}|
&=|1+(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))|\\
&=|1-\cos(x)-i\sin(x)|\\
&=\sqrt{(1+\cos(x))^2+\sin^2(x)}\\
&=\sqrt{1+2\cos(x)+\cos(x)^2+\sin^2(x)}\\
&=\sqrt{2+2\cos(x)}\\
&=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+\cos(x)}\\
&=2\sqrt{(1+\cos(x))/2}\\
&=2|\cos(x/2)|\\
(a+ib)(c+id)
&=(ac-bd)+i(ad+bc)\\
|(a+ib)(c+id)|
&=\sqrt{(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{a^2c^2-2abcd+b^2d^2+a^2d^2+2abcd+b^2c^2}\\
&=\sqrt{a^2c^2+b^2d^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2}\\
|(a+ib)||(c+id)|
&=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{c^2+d^2}\\
&=\sqrt{a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2}\\
&=|(a+ib)(c+id)|\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thank you very much for putting so much effort in writing the answer. I am a bit confused because the results do not coincide numerically (at least for some examples). There might be a mistake somewhere.

Comment: How do they differ? What is the ratio of the two answers?

Comment: For example, if $d=7$ and $n=100$, I obtain $87.10381$ using the absolute value of the sum  and $96.67696$ if I use the formula in your answer.

Comment: The correct expression is $$\frac{|\sin(\pi\{n/d\})|}{|\sin(\pi/n\cdot\{n/d\})|}.$$ So there must be a mistake somewhere in your calculations. Nevertheless, thank you for your help!

Comment: I'll check. The ratios of the args are correct.

Comment: Since $na = \{n/d\}$, I'm off by a factor of 2.

Comment: Aha! The original has $2\pi$. I used $\pi$. That explains it. That makes the final answer match.

Comment: It is now fixed. I added a lower bound as you asked.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{y\}=y-\lfloor y\rfloor$ denote the fractional part of $y$. Inside the modulus signs we have the geometric series
$$
\sum_{t=1}^n \exp\bigg( \frac{2\pi i}n \Big\{ \frac nd \Big\} t \bigg) = \sum_{t=1}^n \exp(\alpha t) = \exp(\alpha) \frac{\exp(n\alpha)-1}{\exp(\alpha)-1},
$$
where $\alpha = \frac{2\pi i}n \big\{ \frac nd \big\}$ (and we are assuming that $\alpha\ne0$); therefore
$$
x_n = \frac{|\exp(n\alpha)-1|}{|\exp(\alpha)-1|}.
$$
Since $\alpha$ is very small, the denominator is $\sim|\alpha|$ by the mean value theorem, and so
$$
x_n \sim |\alpha|^{-1} |\exp(n\alpha)-1|.
$$
The first term does have size close to a constant times $n$. The second term, however, can be quite small if $\{\frac nd\}$ is close to $0$ or $1$, that is, if $n$ is just more than or just less than a multiple of $d$. In particular, if $d$ divides $n\pm1$, then the order of magnitude of $x_n$ will be roughly $\frac nd$ rather than $n$.

Comment: You have to multiply by $e^{\pi a}$ since the sum starts at $n=1$. I worked it out the hard way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You mentioned that the order of magnitude of $x_n$ will be roughly $\frac nd$ rather than $n$. But that still means that $x_n\sim cn$ as $n\to\infty$ with some absolute positive constant $c$ ($d$ is fixed), right?

Comment: Could you please also explain how you use the MVT to conclude that the denominator is $\sim|\alpha|$?

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb It is not the case that $x_n\sim cn$ for any constant $n$: the ratio $x_n/n$ is bounded above and below but will fluctuate.

Comment: In hindsight, rather than invoking the mean value theorem with these complex-valued functions, it's better if I say that the function $(e^t-1)/t$ has a removable singularity at $t=0$ with value $1$, and so in particular (by continuity) $(e^t-1)/t \approx 1$ when $t$ is small. Apply this with $t=n\alpha$.

Comment: You can get the exact result by using $|1-e^{ix}| = 2\sin(x/2)$.